# How to use Javascript to link from mobile site to full site without getting redirected back to mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, web

I am calling this script from all the pages of my full site to redirect mobile users to a mobile site url.
The problem comes in when someone clicks a link (from the mobile site) to view the full site...the redirect puts the user right back to the mobile site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 700) {
window.location = "http://domain.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Is there something I can add to this JS code that will not allow the redirect to occur if the user is coming from the mobile site url?
I only want to us javascript in my case, so if anyone has a JS solution; that would be what I am looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Set a cookie or use localstorage.

Comment: do you have some js source code for that?

Comment: @AronH http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp What you intend to do is to store/read a cookie before the redirect to see if one or the other has been choosen make the relocation do accordingly. You may also use Sessions based on your server side language

Comment: I don't understand how I would add the cookie script to this specific application.  Please give me an example that I could apply directly to the JS redirect I originally posted.

Comment: @AronH On the link back from mobile.html you can do setCookie (from link above) onclick before sending the visitor back to index.

on this script you can do in one of your IFs  && getCookie('cookiename') != "what you inserted"

Comment: @Iesus Sonesson  I edited the code in my original question.  Can you rewrite your last answer so it uses my new edition of the Javascript redirect in context? This would help me immensely. I appreciate your time very much!

Comment: Thank you!  Does the link, which sets the cookie, need to be updated also to work? or does it not matter?  Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi again, no it does not have to be updated. but you do need to have the functions in your code (found on the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in one way, it will remember the user choice 100 days.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Use the functions from the link i provided: and then change this if;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 700 && getCookie("mobileRedirected")!="true"){
window.location = "http://domain.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

On the link back to that page do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setCookie('mobileRedirected','true',100);document.location='index.html';">LINK</a>
```

Next time user gets to index it will know it has clicked his way away from mobile.html

That is if you wish the user to be able to choose between sites, if not (only show mobile once) you could do this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 700 && getCookie("mobileRedirected")!="true"){
setCookie('mobileRedirected','true',100);
    window.location = "http://domain.com";
    }
    //-->
    </script>
```

And skip the link code all together

Full working example of code above

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
function getCookie(c_name){
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
    if (screen.width <= 700 && getCookie("mobileRedirected")!="true"){
        setCookie('mobileRedirected','true',100);
        window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    </script>
```

You may also window.innerWidth if you wish small browserwindows to be redirected as well.
Working example link: http://allanthya.net/cookietest.php

Comment: When I use my original jscript, the redirect works great.  However, when I use your second block of jscript code above (with the cookie function added in), the redirect doesn't work any more...I'm talking about going from main site to mobile site.  Why is this?

Comment: it only works first time you visit, or else it has the cookie " (only show mobile once) ", or you do not have the setCookie function in your script.

Comment: Well, even after I clear the cookies on my iphone, it won't take me through the redirect from the main to mobile site.  I am using your (only show mobile once) block of script just above this comment, I am replacing "http://domain.com" with my mobile site URL, and placing the whole script in the header of my page.  I also tried placing it in a .js file and referred to the source like this: <scrip src="http://www.domain.com/Javascript/mobileredirect.js"></script> Is there something I'm not configuring right, or anything that makes this not work for me?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AronH I have tested the code and it works great, dont know what the problem seems to be but i'll update with working example

Answer (score 1):

Use the cookie code from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

On click of the link. Set a cookie

```
docCookies.setItem("isMobile","true");
```

when you check for the redirection, read the cookie

```
if (!docCookies.getItem("isMobile"))
```

Comment: Tell me if I understand correctly here...so I need to place those 2 lines below what js redirect code I have already on my main site pages?

Comment: You set the cookie where you do the redirect. You do the if statement where you do the mobile check.

Comment: I think I understand...So I should place the "set cookie" js on the mobile page, and add the "if statement" to my existing redirect js on the main site pages.  Please confirm if this is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, that would be what I was saying.